Trait bound EnumStatus: anchor_lang::Space is not satisfied for Enum
Trait anchor_lang::Space is not implemented for EnumStatus
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum EnumStatus {
  Active,  Paused,  Closed,
}
#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct EnumAccount {
  pub status: EnumStatus, // <-- Error happens here
}


You just need to add InitSpace to EnumStatus derives.
- #[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
+ #[derive(InitSpace, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum EnumStatus {
  Active,  Paused,  Closed,
}

